# How could I implement a look up table operation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Suppose I have map like this:

```
{-1: -1, 1: 255, 2: 255, 7: 0, 8:1, ...}
```

and I have an array `m`. The values of `m` are the keys of the map, and I would like to convert the values of the array from the map keys to the map values. How could I do this with `opencv` or `numpy`?

Answer (score 0):

A NumPy solution would be:

```
def numpy_map(arr, d):
    v = np.array(list(d.values()))
    k = np.array(list(d.keys()))    
    sidx = k.argsort()
    return v[sidx[np.searchsorted(k, arr, sorter=sidx)]]
print(numpy_map(<here you put the numpy array>, <here you put the dictionary>))
```

While using some `pandas` would be much easier, and optimal:

```
print(pd.Series(<here you put the numpy array>).map(<here you put the dictionary>).values)
```